# Google Sitemap Ping Success

Tags: php, ping, sitemap

I have a php script that creates an xml sitemap. At the end, I use

```
shell_exec('ping -c1 www.google.com/webmasters/tools/ping?sitemap=sitemapurl');
```

to submit the updated sitemap to Google Webmaster tools.

Having read the Google documentation, I'm unsure whether I need to do this each time or not. Entering the link in the code manually, results in a success page from google, but using the ping command I receive no confirmation. I would also like to know if there is any way of checking if the command has actually worked.

Comment: I voted to close this question because it is not a programming question and it is off-topic on Stack Overflow. Non-programming questions about your website should be asked on [webmasters.se]. In the future please ask questions like this on webmasters.

Answer (score 8):

Here is a script to automatically submit your site map to google, bing/msn and ask:

```
/*
* Sitemap Submitter
* Use this script to submit your site maps automatically to Google, Bing.MSN and Ask
* Trigger this script on a schedule of your choosing or after your site map gets updated.
*/

//Set this to be your site map URL
$sitemapUrl = "http://www.example.com/sitemap.xml";

// cUrl handler to ping the Sitemap submission URLs for Search Engines…
function myCurl($url){
  $ch = curl_init($url);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
  curl_exec($ch);
  $httpCode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
  curl_close($ch);
  return $httpCode;
}

//Google
$url = "http://www.google.com/webmasters/sitemaps/ping?sitemap=".$sitemapUrl;
$returnCode = myCurl($url);
echo "<p>Google Sitemaps has been pinged (return code: $returnCode).</p>";

//Bing / MSN
$url = " https://www.bing.com/webmaster/ping.aspx?siteMap=".$sitemapUrl;
$returnCode = myCurl($url);
echo "<p>Bing / MSN Sitemaps has been pinged (return code: $returnCode).</p>";

//ASK
$url = "http://submissions.ask.com/ping?sitemap=".$sitemapUrl;
$returnCode = myCurl($url);
echo "<p>ASK.com Sitemaps has been pinged (return code: $returnCode).</p>";
```

you can also send yourself an email if the submission fails:

```
function return_code_check($pingedURL, $returnedCode) {

    $to = "webmaster@yoursite.com";
    $subject = "Sitemap ping fail: ".$pingedURL;
    $message = "Error code ".$returnedCode.". Go check it out!";
    $headers = "From: hello@yoursite.com";

    if($returnedCode != "200") {
        mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
    }
}
```

Hope that helps

Comment: Bing recommends another url (Feb-2016): 

`http://www.bing.com/ping?sitemap=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.example.com/sitemap.xml`


Resource: [Bing Sitemaps](https://www.bing.com/webmaster/help/how-to-submit-sitemaps-82a15bd4)

Comment: @Calaelen I think it doesn't important to replace `http://` with `http%3A%2F%2F` - both are giving the same results.

Comment: Today,  April 2022, the Bing url is: ```https://www.bing.com/webmaster/ping.aspx?siteMap=http://your_site.com/sitemap.xml```

Answer (score 0):

Since commands like `shell_exec()`, `exec()`, `passthru()` etc. are blocked by many hosters, you should use `curl` and check for a response code of 200.

You could also use `fsockopen` if curl is not available. I'm going to check for the code snippet and update the answer when I found it.

**UPDATE**:

Found it. I knew I used it somewhere. The funny coincedence: It was in my Sitemap class xD
You can find it here on github: https://github.com/func0der/Sitemap. It is in the Sitemap\SitemapOrg class.
There is a also an example for the curl call implemented.

Either way, here is the code for stand alone implementation.

```
/**
 * Call url with fsockopen and return the response status.
 *
 * @param string $url
 *  The url to call.
 *
 * @return mixed(boolean|int)
 *  The http status code of the response. FALSE if something went wrong.
*/
function _callWithFSockOpen($url) {
    $result = FALSE;

    // Parse url.
    $url = parse_url($url);
    // Append query to path.
    $url['path'] .= '?'.$url['query'];

    // Setup fsockopen.
    $port = 80;
    $timeout = 10;
    $fso = fsockopen($url['host'], $port, $errno, $errstr, $timeout);

    // Proceed if connection was successfully opened.
    if ($fso) {
        // Create headers.
        $headers = 'GET ' . $url['path'] . 'HTTP/1.0' . "\r\n";
        $headers .= 'Host: ' . $url['host'] . "\r\n";
        $headers .= 'Connection: closed' . "\r\n";
        $headers .= "\r\n";

        // Write headers to socket.
        fwrite($fso, $headers);

        // Set timeout for stream read/write.
        stream_set_timeout($fso, $timeout);

        // Use a loop in case something unexpected happens.
        // I do not know what, but that why it is unexpected.           
        while (!feof($fso)){
            // 128 bytes is getting the header with the http response code in it.               
            $buffer = fread($fso, 128);

            // Filter only the http status line (first line) and break loop on success.
            if(!empty($buffer) && ($buffer = substr($buffer, 0, strpos($buffer, "\r\n")))){
                break;
            }
        }

        // Match status.
        preg_match('/^HTTP.+\s(\d{3})/', $buffer, $match);
        // Extract status.
        list(, $status) = $match;

        $result = $status;
    }
    else {
        // @XXX: Throw exception here??
    }

    return (int) $result;
}
```

If you guys find any harm or improvement in this code, do not hesitate to open up a ticket/pull request on GitHub, please. ;)

Comment: Hi, How will i know if this has worked? I have entered the $url http://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/ping?sitemap=http://www.example.com/sitemap.xml but i get a blank screen after i run the script. (not with emaple.com obviously)

Comment: I have tried to submit the sitemap using this script, but it has not worked. Not sure what I'm doing wrong

Comment: Sorry, that problem description is not really accurate so I can not help you. 
Please update your question (marking it as an update and attaching the new stuff) and show off, what you did and what does not "work" and what it is that you are expecting.

Answer (score 0):

Simplest solution: `file_get_contents("https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/ping?sitemap={$sitemap}");`

That will work on every major hosting provider. If you want optional error reporting, here's a start:

```
$data = file_get_contents("https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/ping?sitemap={$sitemap}");
$status = ( strpos($data,"Sitemap Notification Received") !== false ) ? "OK" : "ERROR";
echo "Submitting Google Sitemap: {$status}\n";
```

As for how often you should do it, as long as your site can handle the extra traffic from Google's bots without slowing down, you should do this every time a change has been made.